# Ionic3 Events: weird behavior of "this" context

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I am developing a mobile app using Ionic3 + angular. I was plagued by a strange behavior of the "this" context.

below is my code in typescript"

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Events, IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, Popover, PopoverController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Cons } from '../../providers/cons';
import { TransLoc } from '../../providers/trans-loc';
import { Util } from '../../providers/util';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-location',
  templateUrl: 'location.html'
})
export class LocationPage {
  loc: TransLoc;

  //handlers
  private _setLoc: (locs: TransLoc[]) => void;
  private _dismantle: () => void;

  constructor(private nav: NavController, private navParams: NavParams, private events: Events, 
    private popoverCtrl: PopoverController) {
    this.loc = this.navParams.get('loc');
    //set handlers
    this._setLoc = (locs) => {this.setLoc(locs);};
    this._dismantle = () => {this.dismantle();};

    this.events.subscribe(Cons.EVT_LOCS_SAVED, this.setLoc);
    this.events.subscribe(Cons.EVT_LOCS_DELETED, this._dismantle);  
  }

  clickMore(ev){
    let popover:Popover = this.popoverCtrl.create('LocMorePage',{loc:this.loc});
    popover.present({ev: ev});
  }

  private setLoc(locs: TransLoc[]){
    if(!locs || locs.length == 0 || !locs[0]){
      return;
    }

    this.loc = locs[0];
  }

  private dismantle(){
    this.nav.pop();
  }

  ionViewWillUnload(){
    this.events.unsubscribe(Cons.EVT_LOCS_SAVED, this._setLoc);
    this.events.unsubscribe(Cons.EVT_LOCS_DELETED, this._dismantle);
  }

}
```

I defined two handlers: _setLoc, and _dismantle, which are used as 
 event handlers respectively for event "Cons.EVT_LOCS_SAVED", "Cons.EVT_LOCS_DELETED"

during testing, the runtime reports an error at statement "this.loc = locs[0];" in function "setLoc(locs: TransLoc[])", with the value of "this" as "undefined"

now the very strange thing comes, I tried the other event(Cons.EVT_LOCS_DELETED), and the function "dismantle()" run smoothly, the "this" in the statement "this.nav.pop();" resolves correctly to the context of the class "LocationPage".

so what on earth is the problem that leads to the different result?

thanks

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply. I will chew on that post, and see what I can do

Comment: do you mean :  this._setLoc = locs => this.setLoc(locs);

Comment: looks like a typo... you missed underscore in subscribe.. `this.events.subscribe(Cons.EVT_LOCS_SAVED, this.setLoc);`

Comment: I am still a bit lost, can you please write  the complete statement? thanks

Comment: In your constructor the statement I mentioned in my above comment,should have **this._setLoc** not this.setLoc. You are sending a function without arrow or bind

Comment: oh, I see. this is a typo! thanks very much.